# Display:none not working in html2pdf

Tags: html2pdf

```
   $content = "<div id='content'> <div style='display:block;border:1px solid red'>Display </div> 
            <div style='display:none;border:1px solid black'>No-Display </div></div>";
            $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
            $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
            $html2pdf->Output('example.pdf');
            $return = true;
```

This leads to the following:
[image]

Obviously, I want the `display:none` section not to be displayed. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this document (http://www.studentenwerk-goettingen.de/pdf/help/compatibility.css.2.1.html) css display support is only partial.

A workaround would probably be to have some kind of conditional check to figure out what is actually needed and then construct your dynamic html accordingly, i guess. This way there would be no need to set anything to "display:none".

Comment: this does not  make sense for two reasons: Concatenation in php is done with `.` instead of `+` and concatenation has nothing to do with the issue at all.

Comment: Sorry, was on the wrong track, did not read your question the way i should have, plus too much javascript lately.